# How to convert list of strings to doubles?

Tags: c#, string, list, double

> EDIT :  I had tried these two  ways before -

```
List<double> doubleList =
stringList.ConvertAll(x => (double)x);

List<double> doubleList =
stringList.Select(x =>
(double)x).ToList();
```

and got this error:

> Cannot convert type 'string' to'double'

I read about something [similiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084493/c-converting-listint-to-listdouble) that convert ints to doubles...but I have List of strings which I need to convert to List of doubles and the ConvertAll() does not work neither the Select extension method. Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: "the ConvertAll() does not work neither the Select extension method" - what's wrong? Compiler error? Exception? Something else? Can you provide code?

Comment: I was getting Error- Cannot convert type 'string' to 'double' but Mark's answer works!!

Comment: You can't **Cast** a string to double (Strings don't implement **explicit conversion to double** --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). You can only **Parse** it to double as shown in the following answers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The select method ought to work if you are using .NET 3.5 or newer:

```
List<double> result = l.Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Here is some example code:

```
List<string> l = new List<string> { (0.1).ToString(), (1.5).ToString() };
List<double> result = l.Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToList();
foreach (double x in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Result:

```
0,1
1,5
```

One thing to be aware of is which culture you are using to parse the strings. You might want to use the `Parse` overload that takes a culture and use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` for example.

Answer (score 4):

You can use linq:

```
List<double> myList = myStringlist.ConvertAll(item => double.Parse(item));
```

Please be aware that parsing doubles and float is complicated - just think of this:

100,00
100.00

-> Different locale settings

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ForEach method of the List

```
List<double> dbl= new List<double>;
stringList.ForEach( str=> dbl.Add( double.parse( str ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
List<string> list = [your strings]
List<double> newList = new List<double>();
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
  double d = 0;
  if(!double.TryParse(list[i], d)) //Error
  newList.Add(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may work: 
    List tmpDouble = tmpString.Select(x => (double ?)Convert.ToDouble (x)).ToList();