# Convert list of string into double then get average value

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there an easy way to directly convert my list of string into double data type and get the average value.

Here is my current list result:

```
["6.3000e-009", "7.3319e-009", "7.8303e-009"]
```

expected result:

```
7.15E-09
```

Any suggestion/Comments TIA.

Comment: Please do some research and if you can't figure it out, include what you have tried in your question. This is something that can be easily found with minimal research.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to convert list of strings to doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3365480/4934172)

Comment: I downvoted this because you have two questions (how to convert strings to doubles and how to get an average of a list of doubles), both of which are super easy to google an answer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq to get the average:

```
var avg = input.Select(double.Parse).Average();
```

Comment: Or simply `input.Average(double.Parse)`

Comment: @DavidG, this won't compile btw

Comment: Yes it will, [for example](https://ideone.com/YEm5U4)

Comment: @DavidG https://dotnetfiddle.net/IffIBu

Comment: I've just shown you it working. I don't know what that site is doing but the code works in my link and in LinqPad.

Comment: @DavidG, seems it works in mono compiler only

Comment: @DavidG, try your code in Visual Studio and let me know the result :D

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk Yes, it doesn't compile in Visual Studio (at least up to VS2017 and .NET 4.7.1).

Answer (score 1):

you can use Linq to objects to do this quite easily

something like..(untested)

```
var result = yourArray.Select( s => Double.Parse(s) ).Average();
```