# how to convert double array into integer in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

I am using C# and I have a List like this `List<double[]>`, I want convert into integer and store all elements in another list like this `List<int[]>`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Check it out... https://www.google.com/search?q=c-sharp+convert+list+of+double+to+list+of+integers&ie=&oe=  You will want to try to Google and search existing SO answers before posting a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Converting List<int> to List<double>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084493/c-sharp-converting-listint-to-listdouble)

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger it's the opposite I guess.

Comment: can you show us what you have tired..? have you tried a google search there are also look up the `ConvertAll` function

Comment: HAHAHAHAHA you got me on that one, @mok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a heap of ways to do this, for example you can use linq like this:

```
List<int> integers = new List<int>();
List<double> doubles = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    doubles.Add(i + new Random().NextDouble());
foreach (var d in doubles)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
integers = doubles.Select(d => (int) d).ToList(); // EVERYTHING IS DONE HERE
foreach (var i in integers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Or you can simply loop through the list or use an iterator and cast them explicitly.

Comment: Thank you @Mok. But, how can I convert string to `List<double[]>` or `List<int[]>`?

Comment: suppose you have a `List` of `String` called strings, you can do this: `doubles = strings.Select(s => Double.Parse(s)).ToList();`

Comment: Please @ Mok how can I implementation [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329681/how-to-read-array-from-database-using-c)